# IONIC 4 & PHP when Build the apk does not work

Tags: php, mysql, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have made an application in ionic 4 that connects to a php file which makes the function of inserting data in a msql everything works fine but at the time of compiling it does not work in androd 9 does not send data or connect to the server. I remember that I did something to make it work a long time ago but I no longer have the source code, I remember that I put something "HEADER" but I don't know where.

This is my ts file

```
'''
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-factura',
      templateUrl: './factura.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./factura.page.scss'],
    })
    export class FacturaPage implements OnInit {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient,public alertController: AlertController,public navCtrl: NavController) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      datos: any = {};
    apiUrl='http://072atizapan.mx/index.php'

    logForm() { 
      let newData={
        funcion: 'correo2',
        datos: this.datos
      }

      this.http.post(this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify(newData))
      .subscribe(data=>{
        if(data=='true'){
          console.log('return');
          this.presentAlert();
        }else{
          this.presentAlert();
          this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/');

        }
      },
      (err)=>{
        this.presentAlert();
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/');
      }
      );
    }
```

this is my php

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept-Encoding, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, Authenticationtoken");

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST'){
    echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
    exit;
       }

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

$datos=json_decode($postdata, true);

switch ($datos['funcion']) {
    case 'correo2':
        getMenu($datos);
        break;
}
```

I've already tried with whitelist and adding permissions on android but it doesn't work for me. I am sure that the php is useful because I had already used what is wrong with me is in the part of TS according to me
Any ideas?

ANDORID CONFING

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://xxxxmx/</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://xxxx/index.php</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

SOLUTION:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />



<network-security-config>
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <trust-anchors>
           <certificates src="system" />
       </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://XXX.mx/index.php</domain>
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://XXXX.mx</domain>
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://XXXX.mx/SAPASA/>
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://XXXX.mx/>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: For people who have the same problem, leave the solution: D

Answer (score 0):

use `https://` instead of `http://`
android updates its security policy that's why in the latest OS does not support http:// URL call.

Happy coding :-)

Comment: If I try it with https this appears to me
"has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Add following header in PHP file :

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

Used Https:// instead of http://, it will work, now days latest OS doesn not support http:// URL , my case it will work.

Comment: How it is different that Shailesh's answer?

Comment: If I try it with https this appears to me
"has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: change the order of header, put content-type-json after "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" and "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " be the first line